# node.js module support for postgres large objects (lo not bytea)

Tags: node.js, postgresql

It seems that "npm pg" (https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) is the prefered module to interact with a postgres database from a node.js script.

nevertheless this module does not support binary large objects in the form of postgres "Large Objects". It only support the bytea format.

Is there a module that I am missing that has lo support ?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to write your own support.  Note that libpq basically just calls functions over an SQL interface.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-funcs.html for more documentation.

If you need to, you can refer back to the libpq client interface docs and then use `\df` to see how to invoke these in PostgreSQL.